# Nested Excel Formula Modification Question

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out whats wrong with a nested formula I created:

[image: The formula]

In the image you can see the three sections the formula is broken up into:

1. is grouping cells into buckets
2. is referencing a separate tab (city density scores) and selecting only if the value is less than or equal the value in that tab
3. is performing a lookup also referencing a separate tab, and pulling in that value as long as that condition is met.

There is a unique key linking all three tabs. If all three conditions/sections of the formula are met, the idea is to return the value "Select" and if not, "Don't Select."
When I ran this formula in excel I'm getting "Don't Select" for cells that meet all #1,#2,#3 criteria, trying to figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is the formula I created. I feel its a small change that I need to make:

```
=IF(AND(OR(AM6="1 to 3 Bucket",AM6="4 to 7 Bucket"),$BK6<='City Density Scores'!$H$6), IF((VLOOKUP(BI,'Rank Competition Vetting'!$A$7:$F$182,5,0))<33%,"Select","Don't Select"))
```

Comment: What is `BI`???

Comment: BI is a cell in the file. Its the unique key in that section of the formula used for the vlookup.

Comment: Try using *Formulas* > *Evaluate Formula* to see what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks, have already been down that road, finding it hard to decipher what the excel evaluate formula results are saying, hence the reason I posted my question here. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: What does just `VLOOKUP(BI,'Rank Competition Vetting'!$A$7:$F$182,5,0)` return?

Comment: That part of the formula is meant to perform a lookup in a separate tab and return values in column 5 if they are less than 33%...that's the third part of the formula. So the goal of the formula is 1: bucket the numbers, 2 return the corresponding value if less than or equal to the cell reference in the city density score tab, and finally for #3 perform a lookup and bring back any values with column 5 being less than 33%. If all three conditions are met, then my formula should say "Select" if not "Don't Select." Hope this helps, and thanks again.

Comment: Put just that portion into a new cell. What does it return? If it's not an error, then something else is the problem. Break the formula down into its parts to isolate the error.

Comment: Agree with BigBen. BI looks like a named range. And if its just a cell, it’s missing a number in the cell address.

Comment: I did that already, I isolated and tested each section of the formula (1,2,3) and they all work fine. The problem I'm having is when I try to bring them together. I think its something with how I am combining the formulas.

Comment: You guys are great, that was part of the problem (BI not having a reference cell number). Thank you both. But my bigger issue remains. The formula is now saying "don't select" for a cell that meets all the criteria...you guys think I'm missing something else?

Comment: @app it would help us help you to add a small sample data set (as text) that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula logic is a little off. The  correct form is <sub>(replace BI6 with whatever the correct cell is)</sub>

```
=IF(AND(OR(AM6="1 to 3 Bucket", AM6="4 to 7 Bucket"), $BK6<='City Density Scores'!$H$6, VLOOKUP(BI6, 'Rank Competition Vetting'!$A$7:$F$182,5,0) < 33%), "Select", "Don't Select")
```

Lets break it down: you have 3 criteria, all of which must be true to return `Select`

You have

```
IF(AND(OR(#1a,#1b),#2), IF((#3,"Select","Don't Select"))
```

This will work if #1 and #2 are TRUE, and fail otherwise (returns `FALSE`) because you havn't specified a False clause for the outer IF.

You really want all 3 clauses in the AND term

```
IF(AND(OR(#1a,#1b),#2,#3),"Select","Don't Select")
```

Now, you say you still get a false negative for a case where you believe all 3 criteria are met.  To me, this points to a data issue - perhaps some numbers formatted as text?  In any case, using the Evaluate Formula tool will help.  You say you are having trouble using it: the process is to

- select a cell containing the formula, then activate the tool
- press Evaluate button repeatedly
- at each click the underlined part of the formula is evaluated.
- read the Evaluation to see if it lines up with your expectation

Here's an example (of my formula) evaluated up to the point where the VLOOKUP is about to be processed

[image]